# Solve this Riccati equation

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve the following Ricatti equation analytically
$$y'(\theta) \pm y(\theta)^2= \eta \cos(\theta)  + \xi \cos^2(\theta) $$.

Does anybody know how to do this cause I failed to do so (by means of standard methods)?

Any kind of ideas are highly appreciated.

Edit: If you were able to rewrite it in a (maybe) potentially useful new form, you may post it (at least) as a comment. Thanks for all your efforts.

Comment: For the equation $y'=y^2+f(x)$, substituting $y=-\frac{w'}{w}$ will transform it into the 2nd order linear homogeneous equation, $w''+fw=0$. Finding an analogous transformation of $y'+y^2=f(x)$ is not too hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general method I believe calls for the substitution $$y=\pm{u'\over u},$$
such that 
$$
y' = \pm{u''\over u} \mp {(u')^2\over u^2}
$$
and the equation becomes
$$
 \pm{u''\over u} \mp {(u')^2\over u^2} \pm {(u')^2\over u^2} = \eta \cos{\theta} + \xi \cos^2 \theta
$$
or
$$
u'' +F(\theta)u = 0,
$$
where 
$$
F(\theta) = \pm \left(\eta \cos{\theta} + \xi \cos^2 \theta\right)
$$